# Accessing multichannel data from MTAudioProcessingTap

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio

I'm using `MTAudioProcessingTap` and [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html) to process some multichannel audio, but am wondering if it supports anything more than stereo? Despite a 6-channel `AVAsset` used to setup the `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters`, I'm still only seeing two channels of data when the tap's "prepare" callback is called:

`static void prepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount maxFrames, const AudioStreamBasicDescription *processingFormat)`

In that callback, `processingFormat->mChannelsPerFrame` equals 2. But where does the `processingFormat` get setup in the first place? Is there a way to change this to match the 6-channel asset? In other words, does the tap support multichannel data? There's not much documentation on `MTAudioProcessingTap` besides the sample project and the WWDC2012 [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/517/) so it's a challenge tracking down the issue. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I've played with MTaudioProcessingTap a little, however, the key is the AVAudioMix not the Tap per say. Having access to the AVAudioMix allows you to add in additional Audio Units (kAudioUnitSubType_NBandEQ is one i've added in this way). look at the - (AVAudioMix *)audioMix method in the sample code. You'll see it adds the asset track. You may be able to add additional AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters for the additional tracks in the asset. Although, based on your needs it might be simpler (and certainly cleaner) to create an audio graph yourself.

Comment: Hey @MDB983, thanks for the comment. To clarify, there's only the one track in the asset, but it's got six channels. In the audioMix method, I'm currently setting `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioMixInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:self.asset];` where `self.asset` is a 6-channel `AVAssetTrack`.

Comment: I have the same question here. In my case I created a 4-channel aac track. So even worse, it doesn't even invoke the "prepare" callback of MTAudioProcessingTap, and just doing nothing silently. Does the multichannel audio have to be 2, 5.1, 7.1 to even be legit number of channels?